# Javascript : continue statement based on several different cases

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way of writing this?  I'm trying to teach myself good javascript coding habits and techniques and this is just one thing I can't see to get my head around:

```
var testData = rowData[1].toLowerCase();
if((testData == "bar") || (testData == "server") || (testData == "service breakfast")){ 
  continue; 
  }
if((testData == "service dinner") || (testData == "to go")){ 
  continue; 
  }
```

This works, but is basically a "brute force" attack at the problem.  I've tried using an array and .match function but there are sub strings inside of testData that it matches on and shouldn't.  Quick example is if testData = 'Server/Bartender', it matches on 'bar' in bartender and shouldn't.

Comment: First, this is better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Second: `["bar", "server", "service breakfast", ...].includes(testData)`?

Comment: When I tried the array approach, I was searching the array for an exact match of testData.  The problem was I couldn't figure out how to get the function .match to match only on whole words.  Does this Help?  PS: Sorry about posting here instead of codereview; I never looked at that site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't respond correctly.  After looking at Karina's answer I noticed you suggested the .includes function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options, depending on preference. 
First off, you might find your code more readable with a simple formatting change:

```
if (testData == "bar ||
    testData == "server" ||
    testData == "service breakfast ||
    testData == "service dinner" ||
    testData == "to go") {
  continue;
}
```

If you don't like that, there's javascript's switch/case statement:

```
switch (testData) {
  case "bar":
  case "server":
  case "service breakfast":
  case "service dinner":
  case "to go":
    continue;
}
```

Or you could test against an array of options:

```
const options = ["bar", "server", "service breakfast", "service dinner", "to go"];
if (options.includes(testData)) {
  continue;
}
```

Or even using regular expressions:

```
const pattern = /^(bar|server|service breakfast|service dinner|to go)$/;
if (pattern.test(testData)) {
  continue;
}
```

My personal preference would be testing against an array of values, but javascript offers lots of options to do what you want; you're free to pick the one that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Love this reply!  It really shows a number of answers that can be used, all based on preference, performance and the number of items that need to be tested against.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var testData = rowData[1].toLowerCase();
var skip = ["bar", "server", "service breakfast", "service dinner", "to go"];
if (skip.indexOf(testData) > -1) continue;
```

Maybe you will find this simpler...

Comment: This actually produced "cleaner" appearing code in the final version that I tried:  if(skiproles.indexOf(rowData[1].toLowerCase() > -1) continue;  I renamed skip to skiproles (something that made sense) when reading the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var testData = rowData[1].toLowerCase();
const continueCaseA = ["bar", "server", "service breakfast"];
const continueCaseB = ["service dinner", "to go"];
if(continueCaseA.includes(testData)){ 
  console.log("caseA")
  continue;
}
if(continueCaseB.includes(testData)){ 
  console.log("caseB")
  continue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hs9vt2zd/

You can try this one :)

.match function works if u have some pattern to check

```
var str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var regexp = /[A-E]/gi;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);

console.log(matches_array);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

I am not sure, that it is your case

Comment: I didn't research the .match function, believing it was a simple string comparison and not a regex (something I'm not versed in) expression.  The includes is slick.  I didn't quite understand CRice's comment about .includes and responded incorrectly.